# Python: NOT search Windows\System32 for pythonXX.dll?

Tags: python, windows, portability

How can one have programs use a Python not listed in the Windows registry, NOT search the Windows System path for the PythonXX.dll?

Given this layout:

```
C:\dev\bin\python.exe
C:\dev\bin\python27.dll          <-- our version
PYTHONHOME=C:\dev\apps\Python27  <-- DLLs, Lib, site-packages, etc.

C:\Windows\System32\Python27.dll <-- incompatible version!
```

We need other programs to use our .dll, but they find the incompatible system one first and fail:

```
SET PATH=C:\dev\bin
C:\dev\apps\3rdparty\foo.exe
   <<fails to start>>

rename C:\Windows\System32\python27.dll C:\Windows\System32\python27.dll.orig
C:\dev\apps\3rdparty\foo.exe
   <<runs just fine>>
```

Deleting or removing the system .dll is not an option, the above is just for illustration. We could kludge it to work moving to foo.exe to `dev\bin\` and thus be along side python27.dll, but that introduces a package maintenance overhead and a host of other integration issues we'd really rather not have to deal with.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a copy of your `python27.dll` in `C:\dev\apps\3rdparty`.

The System directory is always searched before the PATH, but the executable directory comes before either of them - see [Dynamic-Link Library Search Order](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms682586%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in MSDN.

Comment: This might be better than putting foo.exe in the Python bin directory, there are a number of 3rdparty programs for which this is an issue, and duplicating the same .dll for each is not very attractive. In any case thanks for presenting an option I hadn't thought of yet.